# custom JSON output in pig

Tags: json, apache-pig, bigdata

Need customized JSON output--

**source file - abc.txt -**

```
100002030,Tom,peter,eng,block 3, lane 5,california,10021

100003031,Tom,john,doc,block 2, lane 2,california,10021

100004032,Tom,jim,eng,block 1, lane 1,california,10021

100005033,Tom,trek,doc,block 2, lane 2,california,10021

100006034,Tom,peter,eng,block 6, lane 6,california,10021
```

**I have done some parsing operations and below is the JSON output**

Output-

```
{"rollno":"100002","firstname":"Tom","lastname:"peter","qualification":"eng","Address":"block 3 lane 5 california","zipcode":"10021"}

{"rollno":"100002","firstname":"Tom","lastname:"john","qualification":"doc","Address":"block 2 lane 2 california","zipcode":"10021"}

{"rollno":"100004","firstname":"Tom","lastname:"jim","qualification":"eng","Address":"block 1 lane 1 california","zipcode":"10021"}

{"rollno":"100005","firstname":"Tom","lastname:"trek","qualification":"doc","Address":"block 2 lane 2 california","zipcode":"10021"}

{"rollno":"100006","firstname":"Tom","lastname:"peter","qualification":"eng","Address":"block 6 lane 6 california","zipcode":"10021"}
```

Now, I need to append the file name and source to each field

**Expected output-**  source = social

```
"file":"abc", "data": {"rollno.social":"100002","firstname.social":"Tom","lastname.social:"peter","qualification":"eng","Address.social":"block 3 lane 5 california","zipcode.social":"10021"}
"file":"abc", "data": {"rollno.social":"100002","firstname.social":"Tom","lastname.social:"john","qualification.social":"doc","Address.social":"block 2 lane 2 california","zipcode.social":"10021"}
"file":"abc", "data": 
{"rollno.social":"100004","firstname.social":"Tom","lastname.social:"jim","qualification.social":"eng","Address.social":"block 1 lane 1 california","zipcode.social":"10021"}
```

### -------

Please advise how to achieve this, specifically adding the source name to each field in json field output

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would write a UDF what constructs the expected json and write it to disk.
https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/udf.html#load-store-functions

Comment: Please advise a alternate solution besides UDF

Comment: I'm not sure if it's even possible to project field names with '.' in them like "rollno.social" as the '.' is used to acessing fields in a tuple. And if you can't project them with that name I don't know how the standard json storage could do what you want. What about post processing the json after it's stored?